# LISP - Modify String

Tags: string, lisp, common-lisp

I have to write a program that changes a string's vowels, consonants and other symbols into C, V respectively 0. I've done this but I wonder if there is a more efficient and elegant way to do it. Would appreciate input.

```
(defun string-to-list (string)
(loop for char across string collect char))

(defun is-vowel (char) (find char "aeiou" :test #'char-equal))

(defun is-consonant (char) (find char "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz" :test #'char-equal))

(defun letter-type (char)
(if (is-vowel char) "V"
(if (is-consonant char) "C"
"0")))

(defun analyze-word (word-string)
(loop for char across word-string collect (letter-type char)))
```

Moreover, I would like to make it a string, how could I do that? Should I define a function that would iterate through the list and make it a string or is it an easier way to do it?

Comment: This question should be better asked at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Use 'MAP' instead. It would help if your format and indent your code according to typical conventions.

Comment: I don't know how to use `MAP` , could you help me out?

Comment: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_map.htm

Comment: Please invest a few minutes to [learn how to format Lisp code](http://dept-info.labri.u-bordeaux.fr/~idurand/enseignement/PFS/Common/Strandh-Tutorial/indentation.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
(defun letter-type (char)
  (cond ((find char "aeiou" :test #'char-equal) #\V)
        ((alpha-char-p char) #\C)
        (t #\0)))

CL-USER> (map 'string #'letter-type "analyze-word")
"VCVCCCV0CVCC"
```

Comment: Though when I type in "spectacuular22ace" it gives me "VCVCCCV0CVCC" and spectacular starts with a v which is a consonant not a vowel and more than that, it only prints one 0 and not two 0.

Comment: You have to replace the "analyze-word" in the above example with your input.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of the idea:

```
(defun multi-replace-if (sequence function &rest more-functions)
  (map (type-of sequence)
       (lambda (x)
         (loop for f in (cons function more-functions)
            for result = (funcall f x)
            while (eql x result)
            finally (return result)))
       sequence))

(multi-replace-if "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"
                  (lambda (x) (if (find x "aeiouy") #\v x))
                  (lambda (y) (declare (ignore y)) #\c))
"cccccccccccccccccccvc"
```